# Which value is stored in android.os.Build.HOST?

Tags: android, build, host

Looking into the documentation ( http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html#HOST ) I find no description or explanation for this value.

For instance my phone stores the value `r720-PowerEdge-R720` in this field. However, others have different values that do not seem to follow a common URL pattern.

So, what kind of value is store in this field?
Is it unique?
How is it determined?

Comment: Well, the PowerEdge R720 is the name of a Dell server model. Perhaps it's the machine that compiled the AOSP.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/os/Build.java), it refers to `ro.build.host`:

```
// The following properties only make sense for internal engineering builds.
public static final long TIME = getLong("ro.build.date.utc") * 1000;
public static final String USER = getString("ro.build.user");    
public static final String HOST = getString("ro.build.host"); //line 773
```

Which is apparently used for `internal engineering builds`. There is also no really information about ro.build.host [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=32080019), except the title of the section:

> This mentions that the build prop is built by build info shell script during the compilation of the ROM.